# Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015 Update Fail

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, installation

When I start up a Xamarin project in VS 2015 (I'm just learning Xamarin), I get a notification that there's an update for Xamarin for Visual Studio.

[image: "Update Available"]

I follow the trail, click on all default settings, and eventually get here:

[image: Update Downloaded]

I click "Install", give it Administrator permission, it runs for about a minute, and repeatably I get to here:

[image: Update fails with Error 2503.]

I click OK, and immediately I get this:

[image: Update fails with error 2502.]

I tried what I could find on the Web regarding any not-specific-to-Xamarin "Error 2503". Nada. There is nothing from Xamarin on this (that I can find).

Oh! Is this relevant? I have had VS 2013 installed too and it works fine. VS 2015 and Xamarin are relatively new.

Suggestions?

Comment: instead of update, re-run the Visual Studio Community with Xamarin for Windows from here: https://www.xamarin.com/download

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 Pro, not Community.

Comment: Ok, so the best to do is to follow @clb answer then.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like there is a corrupted installer in your update cache. Are you able to try to reinstall independent from the downloaded version? You should be able to download anew from:

http://download.xamarin.com/XamarinforVisualStudio/Windows/Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.1.0.530.msi

Thanks!

Comment: While I'm downloading the above update (389 MB, 1 hour to download), let me ask another question. How do I empty my "update cache"?

Comment: Hey! It should be: C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\XamarinStudio-5.0\Cache\TempDownload or you can just do %appdata% for the shortcut.

Comment: No. Sorry. It didn't work. Same result, same error codes.

Answer (score 0):

The errors are caused by a permissions problem on **%Temp%**.
Give your username Full Control permission on your %Temp% folder (and sub-folders thereof) and the errors go away.